# How to solve stack size too large error.

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javassist

In my maven project, one of the class injects some int values to a byte-code (using javassist) and it also injects an return statement which returns an int array with those injected values. Also I am having a testng class which invokes the logic to do the injection.

1) When I am trying to execute the test case,it gets executed successfully.

2) When I try to execute the following commands separately by right clicking the project,

1. runas-> maven clean, then
2. maven-> update maven project, then
3. runas -> maven install
   it gets executed successfully.

3) When I am trying to  execute maven clean, install from command line using the command "clean install", it shows an error that "java.lang.verifyError: Stack size too large" in that testng method.

Can anyone please provide the command line input for 
(1.maven clean,
2.maven update project,
3.maven install) at the same time.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might look for mvn clean install -U.